# How do i get my buttons to stay in the middle under my image slider?

Tags: html, css

I've two buttons I want to stay in the middle of my slider no matter how big the screen is. How can I do this, now they're just jumping around when I change the size of the screen. When I have the biggest and the smallest sizes it looks okay but not when it is in between...

```css
.buttonright {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 90px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonleft {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 90px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slide {
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  min-width: 500px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .slide {
    margin-left: 14%;
  }
}

#buttons {
  margin-left: 27%;
  width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  #buttons {
    margin-left: 18%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">

  <div id="buttons">
    <button class="buttonleft" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="buttonright" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a reminder, please mark the answer that helped answer your question the most as the accepted answer. It will help others in the future who might have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this wat u want?

I added `text-align:center` to main div (slide), so everything inside it will be centered

```css
.buttonright {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 90px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonleft {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 90px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slide {
  margin-top: 20px;
  min-width: 500px;
}

.center{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide center">
  <img class="mySlides" src="1.jpg" style="width:70%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="2.jpg" style="width:70%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="3.jpg" style="width:70%">

  <div id="buttons">
    <button class="buttonleft" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="buttonright" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using Flexbox:

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.slides {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slide {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.buttonleft,
.buttonright {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 90px;
  margin: 7.5px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slides">
    <img class="slide" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <img class="slide" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <img class="slide" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
  </div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="buttonleft" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="buttonright" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution

```css
#buttons {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.slide {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.buttonright, .buttonleft {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 90px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
  <img class="mySlides" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">

  <div id="buttons">
    <button class="buttonleft" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="buttonright" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```